# Angular4 - displaying array element in html

Tags: html, arrays, angular

Here is my function that takes resLS as an object array. I am trying to display arr in html element using Angular 4.  But when I do {{arr}}, I don't see anything in html. I was expecting to see some element appended in arr array and I definitely see data in console. What am I missing?

```
findLastValueLS(resLS, name: String) {
let index = resLS.NewDataSet.Table.findIndex(d => d.DataPointName[d.DataPointName.findIndex(DataPointName => DataPointName === name)]);
console.log(resLS.NewDataSet.Table[index].LastValue);
var arr = []; 
arr.push(resLS.NewDataSet.Table[index].LastValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your html code

Comment: it's just <div> {{arr}}</div>

Comment: You can use the [JSON pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#jsonpipe) for this `{{ arr | json }}`. Or even `<pre>{{ arr | json }}</pre>` for a more readable output.

Comment: still not seeing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ngFor   :

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of arr">
      Name : {{ item }}
  </div>
```

Comment: i don't get any item values.

Comment: I just checked. It lists of array as expected in console.

Comment: <button (click)="logMe()">
</button>

Comment: i replaced logMe() with my function, and once I click it says that it cannot read property of object somehow .. why is that ?

Comment: what is resLS's type ?

Comment: It's JSON consists of string and array

Comment: use JSON.parse( to parse elements before pushing them

Comment: I already did while requesting the web service. so resLS is right after applying JSON.parse

Comment: you have to make arr global variable in ts class so it will be  will be  var arr = [];    findLastValueLS(resLS, name: String) {
let index = resLS.NewDataSet.Table.findIndex(d => d.DataPointName[d.DataPointName.findIndex(DataPointName => DataPointName === name)]);
console.log(resLS.NewDataSet.Table[index].LastValue);

arr.push(resLS.NewDataSet.Table[index].LastValue);
}

Comment: I tried. still not working. I had to this.arr inside of my func.

Comment: outside the function arr is null so it will not populate values , you have to make it ouside and use this.arr inside

Comment: okay working now. but what is difference between arr = []; and arr : any [] ?

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngFor if you are using Angular, or ng-repeat if you are using AngularJS. See the documentation:

AngularJS : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat
Angular:https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Sample for Angular:

```
<div *ngFor='item of arr'> {{item}} </div>
```